# maple: simplify a*f(x)=0 assuming a>0

Tags: math, simplify, maple

I would like to simplify the expression a*f(x)=0, where a>0, using Maple.
I expect Maple to give me f(x)=0, but fail.

In maple, I type
(simplify(f(x)*a = 0) assuming (0 < a));
But it gives:
f(x) a = 0

Thanks!

Comment: I think Maple gave you the right answer.  Are you asking Maple to give you the roots of f(x) = 0?  If a > 0, this is the only answer possible.

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; I think you'll find a more suitable audience at math.stackexchange.com, or perhaps in a Maple-specific forum.

Comment: let's go even simpler, consider simplify( f( x )^2 = 0 )  or simplify( 2*f(x) = 0 ), would you receive f(x) = 0? No. Then why do you think with assuming you will get that?

Comment: I use Mathematica instead, but thanks for replying!